# Centering 2 different elements with different widths using only absolute\left, how do I calcute the offset?

Tags: css

Here's an example to better explain what I'm trying to achieve and what I have soo far...

```css
.side-a {
  width: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 180px);
}

.side-b {
  width: 280px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
}


/* Desired output */

.desired-side-a {
  width: 80px
}

.desired-side-b {
  width: 280px
}

.desired-output {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
}
```

```html
<body style="width: 100%">
  <p>Trying to achieve this (Perfectly centered):
  <div class="desired-output">
    <div class="desired-side-a" style="background: red;text-align:center">ABC</div>
    <div class="desired-side-b" style="background: blue;text-align:center">DEF</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p>With only absolute and left (Centered with trial and error - not perfect):
  <div class="side-a" style="background: red;text-align:center">ABC</div>
  <div class="side-b" style="background: blue;text-align:center">DEF</div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p>The top 1 is perfectly positioned since it's just centered the div container. The bottom one, I have to guess what the offsets would be when using calc(50% - xxxx) and playing with it until I can get it as centered as I can. How do I calculate the
      exact pixels for each offset to get the same result above?</p>
</body>
```

```
     1234px           (Center Point)            1234px
       /\                   |                     /\
|-------------[side-a][-------side-b-------]-------------|
```

But simply, I'm just trying to figure out how I would calculate the number of pixels to offset both divs after they are centered with "left: 50%" without guessing the amount and putting different numbers until I get it right. This is based off side-a that is 80px and side-b that is 280px.

Hopefully I explained this good enough, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS variables and you can have a generic formula. You can also consider the use of `right` to have exactly the same value:

```css
:root {
  --wa: 80px;
  --wb: 280px;
}

.side-a {
  width: var(--wa);
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - (var(--wa) + var(--wb))/2);
}

.side-b {
  width: var(--wb);
  position: absolute;
  right: calc(50% - (var(--wa) + var(--wb))/2);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="side-a" style="background: red;text-align:center">ABC</div>
  <div class="side-b" style="background: blue;text-align:center">DEF</div>
</div>

<div style="padding-top:50px;--wa:100px;--wb:50px;">
  <div class="side-a" style="background: red;text-align:center">ABC</div>
  <div class="side-b" style="background: blue;text-align:center">DEF</div>
</div>

<div style="padding-top:80px;--wa:150px;--wb:150px;">
  <div class="side-a" style="background: red;text-align:center">ABC</div>
  <div class="side-b" style="background: blue;text-align:center">DEF</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! After messing around for a while, I had come up with this, but yours is much better. ----------

.side-a{left: 50%; transform: translate(calc(((100% + 280px) / -2)))} --------- .side-b{left: 50%;transform: translate(calc(((100% - 80px) / -2)))}

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuming that you can't touch the html and have limited CSS access, which is why you have to do this with just those 2 CSS attributes.)

Your numbers are correct, it's just that you failed to account for the 8px of margin around the body. You need to set `body` to be `position: relative` so that the absolutely positioned child items will be correctly positioned relative to it. You can also set the `body` to be `margin: 0`.

Also, here's how I confirmed your numbers, just in case it's helpful if you need to recalculate them for different widths:

```
                      (Center Point)         
                            |                  
|----- x -----[  a  ][-------  b  -------]----- x -----|

W = width of body = a + b + 2x

x = 1/2 W - 1/2 (a + b)
```

So the `left` value of `.side-a` would be `x` (which is `50% - 180px`) and the `left` value of `.side-b` would be `x + a` (which is `50% - 100px`).